# Why are escape characters being added to the value of the hidden input

Tags: php, html, json

```
<body>
  <div> <?= $_POST['msg'] ?> </div>
  <form id="frm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name='msg' value='{"field0": "Im a string", "field1": 84, "field3": "so am I"}' />
    <input type="submit" value="test" />
  </form>
</body>
```

When the form is posted, the following string is displayed between the div tags.

> {\"field0\": \"Im a string\",
>   \"field1\": 84, \"field3\": \"so am
>   I\"}

Why are the escape characters being added?
Are they being added by the PHP server or the web client?
Can I do anything to prevent this?

Someone already mentioned the PHP function stripslashes.  I'm using it for now but I want to get rid of the slashes all together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether your PHP configuration has [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) activated, in such case the PHP server automatically adds slashes to GET/POST/cookie values...

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is just one of escaping done by the tools you are using to output the string. For example:

```
var msg = dojo.toJson({field1: 'string', field2: 84, field3: 'another string'});
alert(msg);
```

will show the double quotes as unescaped. Similarly, running your first example while the browser is hooked up to a proxy like Charles, shows the double qoutes as unescaped.

So I believe this is just an auto-escape that Firebug/PHP does when showing you strings.

Answer (score 1):

If the information is correct when it leaves the client, then dojo must be doing some wizardry before sending the info over to $_POST, no? Are there any flags that you can set for the dojo.toJson() method that will allow you to control the level of input string manipulation / escaping?
If not, I think using stripslashes() (or whatever, depending on where this information is headed) is the only answer.

Comment: I don't think dojo is doing anything funky because frm.submit() is plain ole javascript and request.value == msg prior to submitting the form.  However, +1 for stripslashes(). I'll use it until I figure out what is going.

Answer (score 1):

check if magic quotes is enabled on your host

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you hav magic_quotes_gpc enabled on your server. This configuration option and feature is deprecated in php5.3. Until you upgrade:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
    foreach (array('POST', 'GET', 'REQUEST', 'COOKIE') as $gpc)
        $GLOBALS["_$gpc"] = array_map('dequote', $GLOBALS["_$gpc"]);
}

function dequote($v) {
        return is_array($v) ? array_map('dequote', $v) : stripslashes($v);
}
```

The above solution is based on someone's code i've found somewhere a few years ago.