# PHP, why do you escape my quotes?

Tags: php, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are escape characters being added to the value of the hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038980/why-are-escape-characters-being-added-to-the-value-of-the-hidden-input)

So, I have a file called Save.php.

It takes two things: a file, and the new contents.

You use it by sending a request like `'/Resources/Save.php?file=/Resources/Data.json&contents={"Hey":"There"}'`.

..but of course, encoding the url. :) I left it all unencoded for simplicity and readability.

The file works, but instead of the contents being..

```
{"Hey":"There"}
```

..I find..

```
{\"Hey\":\"There\"}
```

..which of course throws an error when trying to use `JSON.parse` when getting the JSON file later through XHR.

To save the contents, I just use..

```
file_put_contents($url, $contents);
```

What can I do to get rid of the backslashes?

Comment: Just before you save the contents to the file, what does the `$_GET['contents']` have? Does it have `{"Hey":"There"}` or `{\"Hey\":\"There\"}`?

Comment: They show up when using echo as well, but I don't use PHP an awful lot, it might add them too or something. xD

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220437/magic-quotes-in-php

Comment: It has already been answered, but gave you an answer tailored to your situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are escape characters being added to the value of the hidden input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1038980/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turn [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/manual/security.magicquotes.php) off in PHP.ini.

Comment: Magic is never good in development.

Comment: I use the preinstalled version of PHP in Mac OS 10.6, so I've never actually seen PHP.ini anywhere. Do you have any idea where it would be?

Comment: Found it. Google is the best thing ever. Turned it off and now everything works fine. :D

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/security.magicquotes.php) turned on.

If that is the case, either turn it off - Or use a [runtime disabling function](http://php.net/manual/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

Answer (score 3):

you probably have magic quotes enabled, only two things you can do. disable magic quotes in your php.ini or call `stripslashes()` on `$_GET` and `$_POST` globals.

FYI, use `$_GET['contents']` as opposed to `$contents`; newer versions of php will not create the `$contents` var.

Comment: I create it manually earlier in the script.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
file_put_contents($url, stripslashes($contents));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should disable `magic_quotes` in your php.ini configuration file. However if this is not possible you can also use the `stripslashes()` function to get rid of the automatic escaping.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not get magic quotes switched off for your server, then you need to check if it is switched on using [`get_magic_quotes_gpc()`](http://php.net/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc) and if it is true, [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/function.stripslashes).