# Extracting data elements from json string

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using the following script to my php script on my server;

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://xx.php',
            data: { anyNumber: val1 },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
});
```

the php script correct queries sqlsrv database and returns row of data that I encode with
echo json_encode($rows);
I then correctly receive the json string into data (as above example)
When I display the data with `alert(data);` as above, I get the following:

```
"({\"id\":1,\"Username\":null,\"Category\":null,\"VIN\":null,\"Make\":null,\"Model\":null,\"Colour\":null,\"Registration\":\"12345     \",\"RegisterNumber\":null,\"EngineNo\":null,\"Branding\":null,\"Remarks\":null,\"Photo1\":null})"
```

I have tried various methods but cannot assign the various elements to variables.
Please help

Comment: Is this your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324614/php-why-do-you-escape-my-quotes

Comment: I made the following changes: 1. inserted dataType 'json' as suggested. I have also changed the php script to individually populate the $rows array by element inside the loop. This resulted in a response of [object Object], [object Object], etc for each element in alert(data). I can now however correctly and easily access each element by assigning each element as a variable example: var tt = result[5].result;
                and I get the correct value. This works for me but not sure if this is the most appropriate approach. rgs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set the `dataType` of your `$.ajax` call to `json`:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://xx.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { anyNumber: val1 },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
});
```

**explanation:** when delivering data with `GET` or `POST` a lot of characters are getting masked. I think your `$.ajax` call just doesn't expect `JSON` as an answer but text or html. that's why it's not reading the `JSON` string correctly and keeping the masking of the characters.