# How to pass an array of objects from javascript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

If I have, in javascript, something like:

```
entriesObj1 = new Object();
entriesObj1.entryId = "abc";
entriesObj1.mediaType = 2;
entriesObj2 = new Object();
entriesObj2.entryId = "def";
entriesObj2.mediaType = 1;

var entries = new Array();

entries[0] = entriesObj1;
entries[1] = entriesObj2;
```

What is the best method to pass it to php through an HTTP POST?

I've tried a jQuery plugin to convert the array to JSON. I've tried to create multiple hidden fields named "entries[]", each one with the JSON string. Somehow, I can't seem to decode my data with PHP's `json_decode`.

EDIT:
I tried changing the JSON plugin used to the one @Michal indicated and the results I get are the same:

Javascript

```
[
    {"disciplina":"sdfsdfsdfsd","titulo":"sdfsdfsdf","componentes":"Bloco Completo"},
    {"disciplina":"sdfsdfsdfsd","titulo":"sdfsdfsdf","componentes":"Bloco Completo"}    
]
```

PHP Vardump:

> ```
> string(756) "
> [
>     {\"disciplina\":\"sdfsdfsdfsd\",\"titulo\":\"sdfsdfsdf\",\"componentes\":\"Bloco Completo\"},
>     {\"disciplina\":\"sdfsdfsdfsd\",\"titulo\":\"sdfsdfsdf\",\"componentes\":\"Bloco Completo\"}
> ]
> "
> ```

When I use PHP's `json_decode`, I get NULL.

```
var_dump(json_decode($_REQUEST['entries']));
```

Output:

> ```
> NULL
> ```

Comment: Could you post the code you tried?

Comment: And also post the string result of the javascript encode to JSON please.

Comment: can you please take a look at my EDIT? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are escape characters being added to the value of the hidden input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1038980/), [PHP, why do you escape my quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6324614/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the trouble seemed to be with the quotes that were being passed in the post, so i just replaced the quotes with open strings to my $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert JSON to a string (use JSON stringifier (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) and POST the string (as a field value) to the PHP script which does json_decode()

Answer (score 1):

Concat it using some characters like `_` or `%%` then pass it to PHP.

In PHP file:

```
$ar = array();
$ar = explode('special_char',string pass from js);
echo "pre";print_r($ar);
echo "/pre";
```