# single quote and double quote as displaying as \' and \" after INSERT to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am getting strange behaviour for `mysqli` insert. On windows(localhost development PC) it is working fine, but on Linux (Shared Hosting), its not working as expected.

I have field `height` defined as `VARCHAR(10)`. When reading data using `SELECT` statement :

`5' 6"` is displayed as `5\' 6\"`

Table Structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_details` (
  `uname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `height` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `body_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `hair_color` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `eye_color` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uname`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uname` (`uname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Code to Read data**

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * from user_details WHERE uname = ?");
$statement->bind_param("s", $uname);

$statement->execute();

if ($statement->bind_result($uname, $height, $body, $hair, $eye, $desc) && $statement->fetch())
{
    // work with data.
}
```

**Code used for INSERT**

save_data.php

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user_details VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$statement->bind_param("ssssss", $_POST['uname'], $_POST['height'], $_POST['body'], $_POST['hair'], $_POST['eye'], $_POST['description']);

if ($statement->execute())
{
    echo "<div>Username successfully added</div>";

}
```

**save_data.html**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name (Must be unique) : </td><td><input type="text" name="uname"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Profile Image : </td><td><input type="file" name="pic"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Height : </td><td><input type="text" name="height"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Body Type: </td><td><input type="text" name="body"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Hair Color: </td><td><input type="text" name="hair"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Eye Color: </td><td><input type="text" name="eye"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Description: </td><td><textarea name="description" rows="5"></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save New User"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Display on Linux vs Windows

**Linux**

[image: Linux Shared hosting]

**Windows**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are escape characters being added to the value of the hidden input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038980/why-are-escape-characters-being-added-to-the-value-of-the-hidden-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the server to see if magic_quotes are set on. And if (as I suspect they are), turn them off.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.